# ListError [ReferencesWidget] Invalid index N

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Error alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCIlz.png)

[ReferenceWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GZzv.png)

In VS Code, Whenever I go to some code through Reference Widget, The error occur and notified the message. This error message is notified when only I use `l` key on Reference Widget with `vim extension`

Is there any way to solve this or to debug this? I tried delete some extension and tried to check log on output. but I couldn't solve this.

```
Version: 1.84.2
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:52:57.054Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a case of a recent regression: [Go to References results in "ListError [ReferencesWidget] Invalid index" (regression in 1.83) #195402](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195402). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".